# Get the right date with slash by regular expression from the String

Tags: java, regex

I have the following String `volltext`:

```
Los 3, PG 3, Lead-Analytiker Anforderungsanalyse / Konzept Servicezeit 1    1   532     7/1/17  10/31/17
```

And I am trying to get the last String in the line `10/31/17`.

With my current code I am getting `7/1/17`. It is important for me to keep
the `KEYWORD`, `MULTIMATCHPATTERN`, `INFORMATIONSEXTRAKTOR`, `ZEILENFUELLER` structure. How should I change the `INFORMATIONSEXTRAKTOR` regular expression to get `10/31/17` String?

**Here is my code:**

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class ZuParser implements BedarfsanforderungParser {

    private static final String KEYWORD = "Los.*PG.*Servicezeit";
    private static final String MULTIMATCHPATTERN = "[\\t\\s]*\\d*[\\t\\s]*\\d*[\\t\\s]*\\d*[\\t\\s]*";
    private static final String INFORMATIONSEXTRAKTOR = "(\\d*[\\/]*\\d*[\\/]*\\d{1,2})";
    private static final String ZEILENFUELLER = "[\\t\\s]*.*";

    private static final Pattern ZUPATTERN = Pattern.compile("^" + KEYWORD + MULTIMATCHPATTERN + INFORMATIONSEXTRAKTOR + ZEILENFUELLER + "$", Pattern.MULTILINE);

    @Override
    public void parse(String volltext, Abruf abruf) {
      // volltext output --> "Los 3, PG 3, Lead-Analytiker Anforderungsanalyse / Konzept Servicezeit 1  1   532     7/1/17  10/31/17"
        fillZu(volltext, abruf);

    }   

    private void fillZu(String volltext, Abruf abruf) {
        String zuDatumstring = getZuDatumString(volltext);

    }


    private String getZuDatumString(String volltext) {  
        Matcher matcher = ZUPATTERN.matcher(volltext);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            String matchString = matcher.group(1);      
            return matchString;
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add expression `[\d\/]+\s+` for skipping first date before matching group:

```
private static final String INFORMATIONSEXTRAKTOR = "[\d\/]+\s+(\\d*[\\/]*\\d*[\\/]*\\d{1,2})";
```

Comment: I works I just had to add the `*` after `[\d\/]+\s*` also as the following `INFORMATIONSEXTRAKTOR = "[\\d\\/]+\\s*(\\d*[\\/]*\\d*[\\/]*\\d{1,2})";`

Comment: I'm sorry: I forgot quantifier after `\s`.

Comment: Also I think you can simplify and improve performance of your expression: i.g., use just `\s` instead of `\t\s`, if it possible replace quantifier `*` on `+`.